# Обход матрицы всеми путями

Tags: c#, алгоритм, матрицы

Нужен алгоритм обхода матрицы всеми путями от начала и до конца. Пример как обходить, есть на фото. При этом, это пример для 3 строк и 3 столбцов, а нужно, чтобы хотя бы строки можно было задавать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вам что нужно в результате получить? Пути в каком-то виде? А может, просто их посчитать требуется?

Comment: Каждая вершина имеет свой вес. Просто нужно сложить и выбрать наибольшее. Но для того, чтобы сложить, нужен алгоритм обхода.

Comment: Ну с весом пути совсем другая задача. Перебирать все пути нерационально.

Comment: Тогда как сделать?

Comment: Динамическое программирование

Comment: Может подскажите, что почитать или вкратце в чем концепция?

Comment: Добавил ещё ответ. А почитать - материалов в сети море.

Comment: Спасибо большое, опробую позже!

Comment: А можете ещё подсказать. Может есть какое то хорошое методическое указание для рекурсии, чтобы разобраться?

Comment: Честно говоря, не знаю. В алгоритмических курсах обычно подразумевается, что рекурсию базово уже знают, и рассматривают более сложные её аспекты. Так-то кажется, что там ничего особенного - хорошо обдумать условие остановки, и вызывать себя же с другими аргументами так, чтобы в конце концов достигнуть остановки (+ понятие локальных переменных). P.S. В решении с дин.прог. рекурсия не используется (хотя может)

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Comment: Задача в вопросе (о переборе всех путей) достаточно простая, если ее трансформировать. Путь из начала в конец состоит из 2 движений направо и 2 движений вниз. Это можно записать как ППНН. Теперь, чтобы получить все пути, вам достаточно перебрать все комбинации: ППНН ПНПН ПННП НППН НПНП ... может быть такая подсказка вам поможет

Answer (score 0):

Для вывода всех путей проще всего использовать рекурсивную функцию.

```
function walk(X,Y, path)
   Если достигнута последняя ячейка - вывести путь. return
   Если не достигнута последняя строка, вызвать walk c тем же X, с Y+1, добавить в текущий путь пару X,Y
   Если не достигнут последний столбец, вызвать walk c X+1, Y, добавить в текущий путь пару X,Y

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void walk(int x, int y, int rows, int cols, string s)
        {
            if (x == cols - 1 & y == rows - 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
                return;
            }
            if (x < cols - 1)
                walk(x + 1, y, rows, cols, s + String.Format(" ({0},{1})", y, x));
            if (y < rows - 1)
                walk(x, y + 1, rows, cols, s + String.Format(" ({0},{1})", y, x));

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int cols = 3;
            int rows = 3;
            walk(0, 0, rows, cols, "");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Если пути нужно просто подсчитать, понадобится формула для числа сочетаний `C(n+m, m)`

Comment: Оххх, у меня с рекурсией очень туго. Не могли бы поподробнее расписать. Мне нужно всего лишь сложить вес всех вершин и найти наибольшее значение.

Comment: ОК, приведу, раз я уже написал, но это не решит задачу для матриц размером 10 и более

Answer (score 0):

В комментах выяснилось, что реальная задача несколько в другом (как говорится, a kind of XY problem).

Задачу нахождения наиболее выгодного пути можно решать с помощью динамического программирования.

Создаём матрицу такого же размера.
Обходим ячейки построчно. Для каждой ячейки выбираем, приходит ли наиболее выгодный путь в неё слева или сверху, и записываем в неё минимум из тех двух плюс собственный вес.

```
 B[i][j] = A[i][j] + min(B[i-1][j], B[i][j-1])
```

Первую строку и первый столбец можно обработать особым образом.